# HTML <input> required Attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My required attribute which i placed inside a row of a table doesn't seem to be working at all.

I tried closing and un-closing the input tags and changing the button type to input type = "submit" but still the problem persist.

```html
<tr>
  <form action="">
    <td><input type="text" id="itn" required/></td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="prc" required/></td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="dt" required/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="qn" required/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="am" required/></td>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()" class="button button3">
      ADD
       </button>
</tr>
```

When I execute the code on my google chrome browser, the browser doesn't show any alert or warnings if i miss out any fields.

Comment: The HTML is invalid, `form` element should be in a `td` element, and no `td` elements inside the form, or the table should be in the form.

Comment: You forgot to close your `form` element.

Comment: Does this have to be in `table`? repeating rows?

Comment: The problem is that, because of the way browsers recover from the errors in your HTML pointed out by Teemu, the inputs *aren't in the form at all*.

Comment: If you are going to use the native form behavior, you will need to provide names for your inputs.  If `add()` is doing all of the work, then provide that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Put you table inside a form. This is  a basic example and use `action`. Inside the `add` function you can put custom validators and submit the form using ajax

```js
function add() {

}
```

```html
<form action="add()">
  <table>
    <tr>

      <td><input type="text" id="itn" required/></td>
      <td> <input type="text" id="prc" required/></td>
      <td> <input type="text" id="dt" required/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="qn" required/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="am" required/></td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="button button3">
      ADD
       </button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: <button> invalid child of <tr>. Also logical to assume that rows repeat

Comment: @charlietfl sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Not your fault...easy to miss stuff like that when OP does it that way

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<tr>
    <form action="">
        <td><input type="text" id="itn" required/></td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="prc" required/></td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="dt" required/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="qn" required/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="am" required/></td>
        <input type="submit" onclick="add()" class="button button3" value="ADD">
    </form>
</tr>
```